# Displaying lines from a text file in rank order

Tags: c#, .net-3.0

I have a text file which contains several lines, many of them duplicates.

I want to depict a list in which the ones which appear the most appear at the top and the least at the bottom.

However, I want to display how many times the string appears next to it in the list.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

A quick 'n' easy way would be to use a `Dictionary` and loop:

```
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("my file")) {
    Dictionary<string, int> items = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    while(sr.BaseStream.Position < sr.BaseStream.Length) {
        string s = sr.ReadLine();
        if(items.ContainsKey(s)) {
            items[s]++;
        } else {
            items.Add(s, 1);
        }
    }

    // You now have a dictionary of unique strings and their counts - you can sort it however you need.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file isn't too big, ie, if it can fit in memory, you can store it in a dictionary.

Make a dictionary of "line of text" -> "number of times it's been seen"

Read the file a line at a time. If the line is already in the dictionary, increment the dictionary value by one. If the line is new, add it to the dictionary and set the value to one.

After the whole file is read, you can pull out the keys/values. Sort by value to find the most occurring value and print the results.

Answer (score 0):

The code for .NET Framework 3.0:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
  private static int Compare(KeyValuePair<string, int> kv1, KeyValuePair<string, int> kv2)
  {
    return kv2.Value == kv1.Value ? kv1.Key.CompareTo(kv2.Key) : kv2.Value - kv1.Value;
  }

  public static void Main()
  {
    Dictionary<string, int> histogram = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("Test.txt"))
    {
      string line;
      while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
        if (histogram.ContainsKey(line))
          ++histogram[line];
        else
          histogram.Add(line, 1);
      }
    }

    List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> sortedHistogram = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>(histogram);
    sortedHistogram.Sort(Compare);
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kv in sortedHistogram)
      Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", kv.Value, kv.Key);
  }
}
```

Test.txt:

```
ddd
aaa
ccc
bbb
aaa
aaa
bbb
```

Output:

```
3   aaa
2   bbb
1   ccc
1   ddd
```

Comment: i had to remove the LINQ part too, it appeared in .NET 3.5

Comment: I replaced the LINQ-based ordering by a System.Comparison<T> delegate.